# Document server

Tags: linux, document-management

I have a bunch of pdfs and other textfiles. I would like some software that scans a folder with all my files, and the presents them on an html page. Preferable some kind of search tool added to it also.

I'm runnings linux, currently centos and ubuntu.

Does a software for that exist, something that is a little bit better then "directory listing"? Or do I need to hack something up myself.

Comment: Are you looking for a Document Management Server or are you looking for something to run locally to index your documents on your laptop/desktop?

Comment: It's more of DMS i'm looking for. I'm going to have it on my home server, and then access it from work or the ipad/iphone/android phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an indexing software like Beagle or Google desktop.

Edit:

You can use a MS SharePoint alternative like [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/).

Comment: I'm lookin for something like that. But that can be installed on a server, and then accessed through a webserver.

Comment: Alfresco can be installed on a server and accessed through a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

check [xapian](http://xapian.org/)

or

[omega](http://xapian.org/docs/omega/overview.html)

you can embed them in your site

Answer (score 0):

You might like [KnowledgeTree](http://www.knowledgetree.org/Main_Page).